# ORA-O6531:Reference to uninitialized collection error

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

In my PLSQL procedure I am trying to pass an array with the name 
  `FRAUD_IP_ARRAY`. When I compile the procedure I do not get any error. 
  However, when I try to test it I got the error `"ORA-O6531:Reference to 
  uninitialized collection error"`. My array creation, procedure, and test 
  codes are as follows.

**1) Array Creation**

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE FRAUD_IP_ARRAY AS VARRAY(50) OF 
 VARCHAR2(11);
```

**2) Procedure (SPEC & BODY)**

```
    PROCEDURE PR_IP_ONAYLA  (P_SIRA_NO_ARR IN FRAUD_IP_ARRAY, 
                          P_GUNC_KULLA_KOD IN VARCHAR2); 


    PROCEDURE PR_IP_ONAYLA  (P_SIRA_NO_ARR IN FRAUD_IP_ARRAY, 
                          P_GUNC_KULLA_KOD IN VARCHAR2) IS 

    BEGIN 
    FOR i IN P_SIRA_NO_ARR.FIRST .. P_SIRA_NO_ARR.LAST 
    LOOP 
      UPDATE WEB_FRAUD_IP_LOG@T_INTERNET_TERS WIP 
      SET WIP.IP_ONAY_DURUMU='A', 
          WIP.GUNC_TAR = SYSDATE, 
          WIP.GUNC_KULLA_KOD = P_GUNC_KULLA_KOD 
          WHERE WIP.SIRA_NO = P_SIRA_NO_ARR(i); 
  END LOOP; 

  END  PR_IP_ONAYLA;
```

**3)TEST CODE**

```
declare 
    -- Non-scalar parameters require additional processing 
    p_sira_no_arr fraud_ip_array; 
  BEGIN 
    p_sira_no_arr(1):='1'; 
    p_sira_no_arr(2):='2'; 
  --  p_sira_no_arr(1,1):=1; 
  --  p_sira_no_arr(1,2):=1; 

    -- Call the procedure 
      pck_web_fraud_manager.pr_ip_onayla(p_sira_no_arr => p_sira_no_arr, 
                                     p_gunc_kulla_kod => 
  :p_gunc_kulla_kod); 
  end;
```

So what is the cause of it and how can I solve this for upcoming problems?
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize the VARRAY before you can use it. For example like this:

```
DECLARE  
    p_sira_no_arr fraud_ip_array := fraud_ip_array('1', '2'); 
BEGIN
```

or

```
DECLARE  
    p_sira_no_arr fraud_ip_array := fraud_ip_array(); 
BEGIN 
    p_sira_no_arr.extend(2);
    p_sira_no_arr(1):='1'; 
    p_sira_no_arr(2):='2'; 
end;
```

For performance reason you should prefer [FORALL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321) statement:

```
FORALL i IN INDICES OF P_SIRA_NO_ARR
UPDATE WEB_FRAUD_IP_LOG@T_INTERNET_TERS WIP 
  SET WIP.IP_ONAY_DURUMU='A', 
      WIP.GUNC_TAR = SYSDATE, 
      WIP.GUNC_KULLA_KOD = P_GUNC_KULLA_KOD 
      WHERE WIP.SIRA_NO = P_SIRA_NO_ARR(i);
```

Comment: Yes, I realized that VARRAY must be declared in the testing part as well. Thank you for the point.